# C# cmdlet dll that references other project dll fails on load

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a C# project used as PowerShell cmdlet - this should be the API to the main function of a product - so I have to reference a lot of dll's in my PowerShell library.

My problem is that customers want to load the PowerShell dll from any location without settings the working directory to the program folder where all dll's are located. But I only can use my PowerShell commands if I open Powershell by a shortcut where the working dir is set to the program files folder like this:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "[reflection.assembly]::loadFrom('.\PSAPI.dll') | import-module"
```

and set also the working dir to my program files folder where the product is already installed.

If I just use

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProduct\PSAPI.dll")
```

or

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProduct\PSAPI.dll")
```

it always fails. Is there a solution for that (without copying all files to PowerShell folder)?

Here is what I try and the error I get - I can't set the referenced dll's in other way - the .NET application is looking in the working dir for referenced dll's - I set the working dir in powershell to ensure I'm in the right directory, but it won't load my module

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadFrom( 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ASG-Remoteesktop 2016\ASGRD-PSAPI.dll' ) | import-module
```

Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or
assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\ASG-Remoteesktop
2016\ASGRD-PSAPI.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
file specified."
At line:1 char:1
+ [reflection.assembly]::loadFrom( 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ASG-Remoteesktop
2016\A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here as you haven't provided the error but if it works from the same directory and not from another, it's probably that the C# DLL uses relative paths.

When the current directory is `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProduct` it doesn't matter if you use the full path or just `Resources\MyFile.dat`, both will end up at the same place. However if you are in root `C:` the relative path will look for `C:\Resources\MyFile.dat` which of course doesn't exist. When you use `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProduct\Resources\MyFile.dat` it doesn't matter what the current directory is, it will always work.

Check your C# DLL for any relative paths and either temporarily change the working directory or use absolute paths instead.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be: add your assembly path `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProduct` to `PSModulePath` environment variable. Once that is done, you can execute `import-module -name <name of your module>` and it will load it from your folder. In that case you won't need to load your assembly explicitly (most probably).

For more details execute following command in powershell and check the details given for `-name` parameter.

`get-help import-module -detailed`